# List Distinct entries based on property and sum of duplicates

Tags: c#, list, lambda

Im wondering I may be asking a simple question, but trying to get a elegant solution. I have a situation where below are the rows

*State*    *Label*  *Value*

1. Alabama    **AB**      9
2. Alabama    **AB**      4
3. Arizona    **AZ**     5
4. Texas      **TX**      6
5. Texas      **TX**      15
6. California **CA**      14
7. California **CA**      11
8. California **CA**     2

Considering the above `List<ValueLabels>` object (each ValueLabel object will have set of State, Label and value), I should generate another list which contains below information.

1. Alabama    **AB**      13
2. Arizona    **AZ**     5
3. Texas      **TX**      21
4. California **CA**      27

That mean, eventually, I should get a unique records based on State property and value property should be sum of all duplicate entries based on State property.

I have used `ListObj.DistinctBy(p => p.State).ToList()` function with lambda expression but I could not add the values to gether.

Can anyone help me in achieving the above? Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: You definitely should group them, and then get the sum. DistictBy is used for getting unique items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work.

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(x=> new {x.State , x.Label })
                  .Select(x=> new YourClass(x.Key.State, x.Key.Label, x.Sum(x=>x.Value) ))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

On solution is using grouping:

```
var result = from o in listObj
             group o by o.State into g
             select new ValueLabels() 
             { 
                 State = g.Key, 
                 Label = g.First().Label,
                 Value = g.Sum(i => i.Value)
             };
```

Comment: This is the one!!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`MyListOfComplextData.GroupBy(r => r.state)
                     .Select(a => new { sum= a.Sum(b => b.code), Name = a.Key})
                     .ToList()`;