# Remove duplicates and sum values in a Tuple List

Tags: c#, list, linq, tuples

I have a List with a Tuple that contains two strings and an int:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> peopleList = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
```

This Tuple is populated from a lookup to a database and using a DataReader with a list of names, numbers and an int.

I want to remove duplicates from the list and count up the ints.

I've looked at this [List Distinct entries based on property and sum of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805792/list-distinct-entries-based-on-property-and-sum-of-duplicates) - which is most similar to what I want but I'm using tuples and struggling to understand how to remove the duplicates and add the numbers properly.

```
var group = peopleList.GroupBy(x => x)
.Select(x => new { Name = x.Key.Item1, No = x.Key.Item2, Sum = x.Sum(g => g.Item3) });
```

I expect to get back a list that has all the people and their corresponding counted sums.

So:

```
James, 12, 5
Jerry, 15, 2
James, 12, 10
Helen, 87, 8
Jerry, 15, 8
```

Becomes:

```
James, 12, 15
Jerry, 15, 10
Helen, 87, 8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you want to `GroupBy` by `Name` and `No` *only* (we want to collect, say, all `James, 12` into one `chunk`), not by *entire* `Tuple`:

```
var group = peopleList
  .GroupBy(x => new {
     Name = x.Item1,
     No   = x.Item2
   })
  .Select(chunk => new {
     Name = chunk.Key.Name,
     No   = chunk.Key.No,
     Sum  = chunk.Sum(item => item.Item3) 
   })
```